# NDSolve solutions for modeling convection-coupled melting

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, physics

I am trying to solve the convection-coupled melting benchmark in MMA 12.3 as presented in [FEniCS/03-ConvectionCoupledMelting-MixedElement-AMR.ipynb](https://github.com/geo-fluid-dynamics/phaseflow-fenics/blob/master/tutorials/FEniCS/03-ConvectionCoupledMelting-MixedElement-AMR.ipynb). This model in MMA is based on the solution from [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253981/modified-heat-transfer-in-fluid-flow/257619?noredirect=1#comment642378_257619) and [energy-transport](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/energy-transport.html). In the simulation, **"Matrix SparseArray is singular"** problem cannot be solved. The final solution may look like this:

[image] (see reference [1](https://github.com/geo-fluid-dynamics/phaseflow-fenics/blob/master/tutorials/FEniCS/03-ConvectionCoupledMelting-MixedElement-AMR.ipynb))

This notebook shows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

sizes = {length -> 1, hight -> 1};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}] /. sizes;


\[Phi][temp_, tr_, r_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(tr - temp)/r])

Plot[\[Phi][T, 0.01, 0.025], {T, -0.6, 0.6}, PlotRange -> All]

tvars = {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
regParam = 0.025;
steNr = 0.045;
Tnr = 0.01;
pars = <|"MassDensity" -> 1, "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> 1, 
   "ThermalConductivity" -> 1/Pr*IdentityMatrix[2], 
   "HeatConvectionVelocity" -> {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}, 
   "HeatSource" -> (1/steNr)*\[Phi][T[t, x, y], Tnr , regParam]|>;
TransientHeatModel = HeatTransferPDEComponent[tvars, pars];


muL = 1.0;
muS = 10^8;

\[Mu][muL_, muS_, phi_] := muL + (muS - muL)*phi;

CFDModel = {
   
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, 
     y] + \[Mu][muL, muS, \[Phi][T[t, x, y], Tnr, regParam]]*
     Inactive[Div][(-\[Nu] Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . 
     Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y], 
   
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, 
     y] + \[Mu][muL, muS, \[Phi][T[t, x, y], Tnr, regParam]]*
     Inactive[Div][(-\[Nu] Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
       y}] + {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]} . 
     Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(p\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y] - Ra/Pr*T[t, x, y], 
   
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, x, y]};


parameters = {\[Nu] -> 1, Pr -> 56.2, Ra -> 327000.0};

tHot = 1.0;
tCold = -0.01;
ics = T[0, x, y] == 
   With[{tHot = tHot, tCold = tCold, tMeltThickness = 0.1}, 
    If[x < tMeltThickness, tHot, tCold]];
icuvp = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, p[0, x, y] == 0};

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
  temp] = {HeatTemperatureCondition[x == 0, tvars, 
    pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> tHot|>],
   HeatTemperatureCondition[x == 1, tvars, 
    pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> tCold|>]};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, True];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], p] = 
  DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y == 0];

bcs = {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
   p], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp]};

pde =
  {CFDModel == {0, 0, 0}, TransientHeatModel == 0, bcs, ics, 
    icuvp} /. parameters;

tEnd = 0.001;


{uVel, vVel, pressure, Tfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[
   pde, {u, v, p, T}, {t, 0, 
    tEnd}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], Method -> {
     "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}, 
         "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}];
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

***Remark:***

1.) do we have time increments problem in this model? To debug the code, **tEnd = 0.001** is already chosen in the original model (tEnd means the total time).

2.) [energy-transport](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/energy-transport.html) model has linear parameters in CFD model, in our case we have nonlinear term (\mu) in CFD model.

3.) (Very) fine mesh is used in this benchmark test, since the adaptive mesh is applied (Fenics solver).

[[image]]  (see reference [1](https://github.com/geo-fluid-dynamics/phaseflow-fenics/blob/master/tutorials/FEniCS/03-ConvectionCoupledMelting-MixedElement-AMR.ipynb))

**Updates:**

1.) ***MeshOptions***

If we test the model from [AlexTrounev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259508/54516), we can find the following error in case we set: `"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}`

[image]

If we set `"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}`

[image]

**Thus, a numerical issue still remains in this post, namely, why we cannot use very fine mesh (e.g. `{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}`) for modeling convection-coupled melting in Mathematica 12.3.**

Reference:

Zimmerman, Alexander & Kowalski, Julia. (2018). Monolithic Simulation of Convection-Coupled Phase-Change: Verification and Reproducibility: Proceedings of the 4th International Conference on Computational Engineering (ICCE 2017) in Darmstadt. [10.1007/978-3-319-93891-2_11](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-93891-2_11).

Comment: Concerning your remark, no you can mix and match PDEComponents with other forms of PDEs to your hearts content. The purpose of the xyzPDEComponents and xyzPDETerms is to make it easier to set up equations. Since in V13. there is not CFDPDEComponent or such you have to use the standard way to set up the equations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have other things to attend to so I can not look at this in more detail now, perhaps in a few days.

Comment: Can you share a PDF of the referenced document?

Comment: @user21 There is one paper in open access on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.03429.pdf

Comment: @AlexTrounev, thanks, this the link is already very useful. I could swear that when I looked at the ref yesterday the ipynb did not render; it does now so I can see what is going on.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM You try to solve this problem directly with using `NDSolve`. Why not to translate Python code to reproduce results using Newton’s method?

Comment: @use21 I have added some new remarks in the post! thanks for your technical support in advance!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Actually my method working on the quad mesh with 1024 elements  corresponding option `"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}`. See update 1 to my answer. It is not working for a fine or rough mesh due to large time step `dt=10` using in benchmark example for Python.

Comment: @AlexTrounev can automatic time step control algorithms be applied for this approach in MMA?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM For what approach in MMA you are talking about?

Comment: @AlexTrounev for this simulation can we set an automatic time step, thus we may change the mesh size.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I didn't see any simulation. Do you mean your code or my code?

Comment: @Alex  based on your proposed Mathematica model, can we use automatic time step in MMA 12.3, in order to change the mesh size? Or we can only use such kind of mesh size in Mathematica, Note that the adaptive mesh is used in this benchmark example for Python (Fenics).

Comment: @use21  I would ask, why are we not able to use very fine mesh to solve this problem in MMA 12.3, see remarks and updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using method described on my [page](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064?p_p_auth=ce9UOzWD). We set timestep `dt=10` same as used in Python code on https://github.com/geo-fluid-dynamics/phaseflow-fenics/blob/master/tutorials/FEniCS/03-ConvectionCoupledMelting-MixedElement-AMR.ipynb

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

sizes = {length -> 1, hight -> 1};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}] /. sizes;



\[Phi][temp_, tr_, r_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(tr - temp)/r])

Plot[\[Phi][T, 0.01, 0.025], {T, -0.6, 0.6}, PlotRange -> All]

tvars = {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
regParam = 0.025;
steNr = 0.045;
Tnr = 0.01;
muL = 1.0;
muS = 10^8;

\[Mu][muL_, muS_, phi_] := muL + (muS - muL)*phi;
dt = 10;
pde = Inactivate[{
    (u[ x, y] - Us[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
          
     Div[\[Mu][muL, 
        muS, \[Phi][T[x, y], Tnr, 
         regParam]]*(-\[Nu] Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
              y}] + {u[x, y], v[x, y]} . 
           Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
     D[p[x, y], x], 
       
    ( v[ x, y] - Vs[i - 1][x, y])/dt +
          
     Div[ \[Mu][muL, 
        muS, \[Phi][T[x, y], Tnr, 
         regParam]]*(-\[Nu] Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
              y}] + {u[x, y], v[ x, y]} . 
           Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
     D[p[x, y], y] - Ra/Pr*T[x, y], 
       
    D[u[x, y], x] + 
     D[v[ x, y], y], (T[ x, y] - Ts[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[{u[x, y], v[x, y]} T[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     1/Pr Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     1/steNr (\[Phi][T[x, y], Tnr , regParam] - \[Phi][
          Ts[i - 1][x, y], Tnr , regParam])/dt}, 
   D | Grad | Laplacian | Div];


parameters = {\[Nu] -> 1, Pr -> 56.2, Ra -> 327000.0};

tHot = 1.0;
tCold = -0.01; tMeltThickness = 0.05;
appro = With[{k = 2. 10^4}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
tin = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x < tMeltThickness, tHot, tCold] /. 
   UnitStep -> appro;
Ts[0][ x_, y_] := 
  Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x < tMeltThickness, tHot, tCold] /. 
   UnitStep -> appro;
Us[0][x_, y_] := 0; Vs[0][ x_, y_] := 0; Ps[0][ x_, y_] := 0;

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
     temp] = {DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == tHot, x == 0],
      DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == tCold, x == 1]};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, True];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], p] = 
    DirichletCondition[p[ x, y] == Ps[0][x, y], x == 0 && y == 0];

bcs = {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
       p], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp]};
Do[{Us[t], Vs[t], Ps[t], Ts[t]} = 
     NDSolveValue[
       {Table[ Activate[pde[[j]]] == 0, {j, 4}], bcs} /. 
      parameters /. i -> t, {u, v, p, 
     T}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega] , 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
               
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}];, {t,
   1, 8}]
```

Visualization of temperature

```
Table[DensityPlot[Ts[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element]  \[CapitalOmega], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", 10 i}]], {i, 8}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Visualization of velocity

```
Table[Show[
  DensityPlot[
   Norm[{Us[i][x, y], Vs[i][x, y]}], {x, y} \[Element] \CapitalOmega], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", 10 i}]], 
  StreamPlot[{Us[i][x, y], 
    Vs[i][x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega] , 
   VectorPoints -> Fine]], {i, 3, 8}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 1. This method working well for time step `dt=10` on the quad element mesh with element number N from 225 to 1024 including `N=400` in the benchmark solution above.

Example 1.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

sizes = {length -> 1, hight -> 1};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}] /. sizes; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5,
   "MeshElementType" -> "QuadElement", 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> .005]; mesh["Wireframe"]



\[Phi][temp_, tr_, r_] := 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(tr - temp)/r])

Plot[\[Phi][T, 0.01, 0.025], {T, -0.6, 0.6}, PlotRange -> All]

tvars = {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
regParam = 0.025;
steNr = 0.045;
Tnr = 0.01;
muL = 1.0;
muS = 10^8;

\[Mu][muL_, muS_, phi_] := muL + (muS - muL)*phi;
dt = 10;
pde = Inactivate[{
    (u[ x, y] - Us[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
          
     Div[\[Mu][muL, 
        muS, \[Phi][T[x, y], Tnr, 
         regParam]]*(-\[Nu] Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
              y}] + {u[x, y], v[x, y]} . 
           Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
     D[p[x, y], x], 
       
    ( v[ x, y] - Vs[i - 1][x, y])/dt +
          
     Div[ \[Mu][muL, 
        muS, \[Phi][T[x, y], Tnr, 
         regParam]]*(-\[Nu] Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
              y}] + {u[x, y], v[ x, y]} . 
           Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
     D[p[x, y], y] - Ra/Pr*T[x, y], 
       
    D[u[x, y], x] + 
     D[v[ x, y], y], (T[ x, y] - Ts[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
     Div[{u[x, y], v[x, y]} T[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     1/Pr Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] - 
     1/steNr (\[Phi][T[x, y], Tnr , regParam] - \[Phi][
          Ts[i - 1][x, y], Tnr , regParam])/dt}, 
   D | Grad | Laplacian | Div];


parameters = {\[Nu] -> 1, Pr -> 56.2, Ra -> 327000.0};

tHot = 1.0;
tCold = -0.01; tMeltThickness = 0.05;
appro = With[{k = 2. 10^4}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
tin = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x < tMeltThickness, tHot, tCold] /. 
   UnitStep -> appro;
Ts[0][ x_, y_] := 
  Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    PiecewiseExpand@If[x < tMeltThickness, tHot, tCold] /. 
   UnitStep -> appro;
Us[0][x_, y_] := 0; Vs[0][ x_, y_] := 0; Ps[0][ x_, y_] := 0;

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
     temp] = {DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == tHot, x == 0],
      DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == tCold, x == 1]};
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall] = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, True];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], p] = 
    DirichletCondition[p[ x, y] == Ps[0][x, y], x == 0 && y == 0];

bcs = {Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], wall], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
       p], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], temp]};
Do[{Us[t], Vs[t], Ps[t], Ts[t]} = 
    NDSolveValue[
      {Table[ Activate[pde[[j]]] == 0, {j, 4}], bcs} /. parameters /. 
    i -> t, {u, v, p, T}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
              
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}], {t, 
  1, 5}]
```

Visualization

```
Table[DensityPlot[Ts[i][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], {i,3, 5}]
{mesh["Wireframe"], 
 Show[DensityPlot[
   Norm[{Us[5][x, y], Vs[5][x, y]}], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50], 
  StreamPlot[{Us[5][x, y], Vs[5][x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   VectorPoints -> Fine]]}
```

[image: Figure3]

Test 2 (this example not working with automatic mesh generation as mentioned by ABCDEMMM)

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5, "MeshElementType" -> "QuadElement", 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> .001];
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 4]

We also can handle case with `dt=2.5` and mesh of 2025 quad elements given by

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

sizes = {length -> 1, hight -> 1};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}] /. sizes; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5,
   "MeshElementType" -> "QuadElement", 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> .0005]; mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Trounex thanks! what is the numerical issue in the original model, since the original model is based on https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/energy-transport.html

Comment: There is no any issue, and it is possible to make several steps up to $t=1.35$ with your code. But we can't compute up to $t=80$ as with a code above. The problem is that DAE solver used for time integration in your code can't make steps with $dt=10$ due to stability condition.   Also we have message `LinearSolve::sing: Matrix SparseArray[<<1>>] is singular.`

Comment: A plot error here: DensityPlot::idomdim: {x,y}\[Element]mesh does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain.

Comment: for the time step issue, since tEnd = 0.001 is ued in the original model, even not working for tEnd = 0.00001;  tEnd means the total time!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Thank you for remarks about plot. I have used mesh for a nice picture, but not publish here. If you like I can add code for computation up to $t=1.35$.

Comment: where is "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure"} in your model?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Mesh generated automatically, we can check mesh with `Us[8]["ElementMesh"]`, then we have out `ElementMesh[{{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, {QuadElement["<" 400 ">"]}]`.

Comment: thanks, to investigate the time increment issue, tmax= 0.001 is applied in the original model and not working, or in other words, why we cannot use  such (very) small  time tmax= 0.001 in NDsolve?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM We can use `tmax=0.001`, but we can't use nondifferentiable function `T[0, x, y] == With[{tHot = tHot, tCold = tCold, tMeltThickness = 0.1}, 
    If[x < tMeltThickness, tHot, tCold]];`. It is why in Python code they used interpolation for initial data, and in my code we used approximation `UnitStep -> appro` .

Comment: thanks for your support!  How to change the mesh size? I try "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}, it shows me the error: FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached. NDSolveValue::fempsf: PDESolve could not find a solution.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Did you try mesh with 100 quad elements? May be it is too rough for FEM solver.

Comment: I have tried ""MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}", I found the new error: NDSolveValue::femnlmdor: The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite the PDE in inactive form.

Comment: thanks for your support again! we may note that adaptive mixed finite elements are used in their work, namely fine mesh. Moreover, triangular elements are also used.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM If you can retrieve mesh coordinate from Python code then I will try to use it with my code. Any way, we can handle case with `"MaxCellMeasure" -> .0005` and `dt=2.5` - see update to my code.

Comment: what is the numerical reason that we cannot use very fine mesh (e.g." 0.0001") for this benchmark in Mathematica?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM We can use any mesh, but not with `dt=10`. Practically my algorithm is explicit-implicit, therefore it has bound for `dt` like $dt<c h^2/\mu$ with `c` dependent on gradient $\mu$.  In a case of fine mesh we need to reduce `dt`, also it takes a time to compute  result even with `dt=2.5`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support again! can automatic time stepping ansys be applied here (explicit-implicit)?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Yes, we can include in `Do` loop adaptive mesh and variable timestep size  as well.

Comment: now I test small time increment dt=0.1 and "MaxCellMeasure" -> .0001, such small time increment cannot solve the mesh issues

Comment: @ABCDEMMM It could be better to generate adaptive mesh as in Python code. You can start a new post, and I will try to help you out with this.